# HTTP POST via JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am working on API, The API supports both HTTPS POST and HTTPS GET methods.

Moreover, it is a security risk to expose Web Registration credentials on a public web site. Instead, use a background HTTP POST (server side) to initiate the web registration.

how can i http post (aspx) via jquery?

Comment: What jquery ajax has to do with ASP.NET or web registrations or credentials? Clarify ur question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method that enables you to post any data you want

```
jQuery.post('Your.aspx', {userName:'someUsername', password:'somePass'},dataType:'json',  function(data)
{
    if(data.logged)
       alert('welcome '+data.logged);
    else
    {
       //invalid
       if(data.error)
           alert('error\r\n'+data.error);

    }
});
```

and then the server part:

```
if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")  && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["userName"] && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["password"]))
{
    try
    {
         bool logged = false;
         //do what you need to do , set logged= true when ok...
         if(logged)
             Response.Write("{\"logged\":\"" + Request["userName"]+ "\"}");
         else
             throw new Exception('Invalid credentials !');

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         Response.Write("{\"error\":\"" + ex.Message+ "\"}");
    }


}
else
    Response.Write("{\"error\":\"Invalid request\"}");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post via AJAX, you can use jQuery's [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method.

```
$('form').post('.path/to/url', $('form').serialize(), function(data){
  alert('posted);
});
```

Or, you could always just use an old-fashioned form:

```
<form action="/path/to/url" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Read here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ or here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/